# SQL Server Dmax speed

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010

I have an access ADP that connects to a specified server/database

I need to get a date from another database on the same server, but the speed is very slow.
How can I make this any faster, without an index?

Testing code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub testing(tablename As String)
Dim q
Dim z As Date
Dim rs
Dim cmd

q = Timer
z = DMax("created", tablename)
Debug.Print "Dmax: "; Timer - q; " Secs"

q = Timer
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandText = "select max(created) from " & tablename
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
Set rs = cmd.Execute

z = rs.Fields(0).value
Debug.Print "SQL: "; Timer - q; " Secs"

q = Timer
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 created from " & tablename & _
                  " order by created desc"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
Set rs = cmd.Execute

z = rs.Fields(0).value
Debug.Print "SQ2L: "; Timer - q; " Secs"
End Sub
```

results:

> Dmax:  102.4297  Secs
>   SQL:  59.87109  Secs
>   SQ2L:  74.80078  Secs

Comment: Domain aggregate functions are known to run slow. That's a given. Did you try to save the query and run it via the [Prepared Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675106(v=vs.85).aspx) so it is precompiled?

Comment: unfortunately, it's a one off for a status screen, so it will only be executed once. Perhaps I should ask the other database owner if they would set an index for me

Comment: @OverMind re: *"Domain aggregate functions are known to run slow. That's a given."* - Not necessarily. For example, I just got Access VBA to do `DMax("n","dbo_zzzTemp")` against a SQL Server linked table the query that was sent to (and executed by) SQL Server was `SELECT MAX("n" ) FROM "dbo"."zzzTemp"`. In that particular case any slowness would be the fault of the SQL Server, not the `DMax()` function.

Comment: Sean: Yes, if this is important then you should request an index. Also, given my previous comment to @OverMind I wonder if your test results might be different if you changed the order of the trials. The second and third trials might be benefiting from information being cached during the first trial.

Comment: @GordThompson Noted. Thank you for that. In this scenario, I was just making note of OP's timing results and "Domain aggregate functions are specific to Access, and this means that the Jet database engine cannot optimize queries that use domain aggregate functions" from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209126). I did not actually know that DMax was interpreted by SQL server in that way, though.

Comment: @GordThompson, yes, If I use domain functions against tables in my database, then I get results in a few seconds. The query I am trying to optimize is running against another database on the same server

Comment: I am hard pressed to think that such queries should occur instant and without delay. The simple addition of an index to the table column [created] should result in these queries running without any noticeable delay at all. Such quires should not take more then say .01 second on average.